# How to remap keys to work with KVM switch

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xmodmap

I have a KVM switch for which the hot-key is `<scroll lock>` `<scroll lock>`. The hot key lets me switch the keyboard, video and mouse from a Windows machine to a Linux machine, but not vice-versa. My recollection is that I used to have it working with an xmodmap remapping, but I no longer have the remapping in my profile and I don't recall what I mapped to what.

I feel like my question is asking how do I remap the `<scroll lock>` key to the `<scroll lock>` key but somehow get a different result. Normally I would say that is stupid, but the keysym columns, the modN keys and the key notation in xmodmap are all black magic to me and I have no idea what I should be looking for. The fact that I do not see `scroll lock` in the list makes me think that something can be done.

```
$ xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        ISO_Level5_Shift (0xcb)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to set the keymap in X11. The one I was initially trying was `xmodmap`:

```
xmodmap -e 'add mod3 = Scroll_Lock'
```

This would work once, but the change is lost after using the KVM switch. Maybe there is a way to make it persistent or be reset after using the KVM switch.

The second way I tried was with `xkb`. I added

```
modifier_map Mod3    { Scroll_Lock };
```

to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc` between `Mod2` and `Mod4`. This works for all users and at the login screen and persists across KVM switching.